# Connecting to a server and running a file with a GUI using bash on Windows and Xming

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the Linux subsystem for Windows and Xming.
I am attempting to connect via ssh to a remote server and run a GUI program in Xming.
After initiating Xming, I run the following commands:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
$ ssh -X user@address
$ ./gui.sh
```

And I get the following error:

```
Unable to initialize GTK: could not open display
```

Exporting the display after I ssh returns the same error.
I have tried using ssh -Y as well.

Is this just a limitation of bash on Windows, or am I missing something?